# How to add the tuple of same keys and sorted

Tags: python, list, collections, tuples, counter

I have string `s = 'a3c9b1c1'` My expected out is `a3b1c10` which has to sort in order of alphabet

I am able to convert into tuples

```
i = iter(t)
m = list(zip(i, i))
print (m)
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in m:
    d[k].append((int(v)))
d
```

my out

```
defaultdict(list, {'a': [3], 'c': [9, 1], 'b': [1]})

d = {k:tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()}
print (d)
```

My out

```
{'a': (3,), 'c': (9, 1), 'b': (1,)}
```

I have added the code with below

```
for k,v in d.items():
    t = ("{}{}".format(k, sum(v)))
    print (t,end='')
```

How to add the value with same key? or without `end=''`

Comment: Will you always want the aggregation to happen in the last occurrence? In other words, why is your output `a3b1c10` and not `a3c10b1`?

Comment: it has to sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve that, just using `zip()` isn't enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will fail if a letter has a double (or more) digit occurrences:

```
s = 'a3c9b10c1'
i = iter(s)
m = list(zip(i, i))
print(m)
# [('a', '3'), ('c', '9'), ('b', '1'), ('0', 'c')]
```

Instead you can separate the letter-digits pairs with a regex and then sum the same letters:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

s = 'a3c9b1c1'
data = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z])(\d+)', s)
# [('a', '3'), ('c', '9'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')]
counts = defaultdict(int)
for letter, count in data:
    counts[letter] += int(count)
# {'a': 3, 'c': 10, 'b': 1}
print(''.join('{}{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(counts.items())))
```

Outputs

```
a3b1c10
```

---

Assuming this was an XY problem and the real input is `'aaacccccccccbc'` (in any order) it's even easier with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'aaacccccccccbc'
c = Counter(s)
print(''.join('{}{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(c.items())))
```

Outputs

```
a3b1c10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'a3c9b1c1'
t = list(s)
#print (t)
i = iter(t)
m = list(zip(i, i))
print ('tuple :', m)
sums = defaultdict(int)
for i, j in m:
    sums[i] += int(j)
print ('dict:', dict(sums))
print ('joined string:', ''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in sorted(sums.items())))
```

Out

```
tuple : [('a', '3'), ('c', '9'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1')]
dict: {'a': 3, 'c': 10, 'b': 1}
joined string: a3b1c10
```